# AWS path based http proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, http-proxy

Does AWS provide any managed service that would allow me to do path based proxying on the same domain? For example http://www.example.com/ should target one pool of instances while http://www.example.com/something should target different servers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

[Application Load Balancers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/) have this capability.

Comment: Or [CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern).

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Application Load Balancer. And [here](http://www.awsomeblog.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2342&action=edit) you can see my sample blog post about it ( using with ecs )